# FastReport.Net : how to add Total in ReportSummaryBand dynamically

Tags: c#, fastreport

I've written this part of code to add summary of the field "Count" to report summary band:

```
Total colTotal = CreateTotal();
colTotal.SetReport(report);
colTotal.PrintOn = reportSummaryBand;                
TextObject colTitle = new TextObject();
colTitle.Text="[" + colTotal.Name + "]";
reportSummaryBand.Objects.Add(colTitle);
```

which CreateTotal function is as bellow:

```
private Total CreateTotal()
{
    Total colTotal = new Total();
    colTotal.TotalType = TotalType.SUM, 
    columnHeader.Agg_Func_Type.ToString());
    colTotal.SetName("CountTotal");
    colTotal.Expression = "[MyTable.Count]";
    return colTotal;
}
```

but i get the error :
  Error CS0103: The name 'CountTotal' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

by applying below changes to the CreateTotal function problem was solved . hope it helps :
thanks to Dmitriy Fedyashov for this link : https://www.fast-report.com/en/blog/68/show/

```
  private Total CreateTotal(Report report, DataBand dataBand, ReportSummaryBand repSumBand, ColumnHeader columnHeader)
    {
        // create total
        Total colTotal = new Total();
        colTotal.SetName("CountTotal");
        colTotal.Expression = "[MyTable.Count]";
        colTotal.Evaluator = dataBand;
        colTotal.PrintOn = repSumBand;
        colTotal.TotalType = TotalType.Sum;                  

        report.Dictionary.Totals.Add(colTotal);
        return colTotal;
    }
```